# we can see as Opentok keep us show to user the internet connectivity latency or quality

Tags: opentok, tokbox

I decided to text you, because I need help with this. 
In the image below, you can see that OpenTok shows the user the internet connectivity latency or quality icon. (the space closed in White circle)

[image: image description here]

I was looking at the documentation and different forums, but I could not find how to do it or show it in Javascript. 
Could you please help me and share where I can find the implementation steps or how I accomplish this?

Thank you so much.
Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

You could use the [OpenTok Network Test JS](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-network-test-js) module to check network connectivity before people join the video chat or you can use [`subscriber.getStats()`](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Subscriber.html#getStats) and [`publisher.getStats()`](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Publisher.html#getStats) for when people are in the video call. These methods return the following:

- Stream quality
- Total audio and video packets lost
- Total audio and video packets received
- Total audio and video bytes received
- Current video frame rate

Please keep in mind that you would have to build the widget based on the data returned from the methods mentioned above.